# cannot run java file in command line that created by eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

If I create Java file by touch command in command line, edit it using nano, compile it by javac, and then run it, all works well.

But if I use eclipse to build the project, and create file in eclipse. I can compile it using javac, but cannot run it in the command line.

it shows

Error: Could not find or load main class

why this happen? is anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

sounds like all about right path in which you trying to run your class.
did you use packages? did you run it from bin|target|build dir?
please provide commands and paths from which you trying to execute it

Comment: yes, i use package when i build project in eclipse.

Comment: what do you mean run it from bin|target|build? is it the path where the file is or the path for java sdk?

Comment: so if you use package - your run command should be something like this: ~/bin/classes/ $ java mypackage.MainApp    . when you build your app in eclipse - its create additional folder ("bin" i guess, but i don't remember), so your class will be in that folder. and you should run java from it, not from sources folder

Comment: yes it's folder where is located your compiled class

Comment: I try to run from bin/ where eclipse create the folder to hold .class file. but still get the same error

Comment: did you run it from ./bin/MyApp/classes/ or from /bin ?  what contains your bin folder?