# Cannot run class files compiled by eclipse in command line

Tags: java, eclipse

I compiled classes using eclipse, but when I try to run them in the command line, it returns "Cannot find or load main class".[Command line.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x116.png)

My class is:

```
package Chapter10;

public class Hfpd10
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("it works");
    }
}
```

I am running the command from within the C:\Users\John\Documents\Java\EclipseWorkspace\HeadFirstDesignPatterns\bin\Chapter10 folder, where the class files are. The command is:

```
java Hfpd10
```

It runs in eclipse and I used the exact same path.

[Eclipse path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeGF8.png)

The only question I could find like this went unanswered. [cannot run java file in command line that created by eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26593260/cannot-run-java-file-in-command-line-that-created-by-eclipse)

Comment: You want to run a java project or class, it must have a main method to run. In your case class `Hfdp10` is not have a main method so that cause the error

Comment: There is a main method in the class https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhLNE.png

Comment: Post the actual code into your question. Makes it easier for people to copy and run it without having to re-type it out

Answer (score 1):

Change to the parent directory and run the following command:

```
java Chapter10.Hfdp10
```

This required is because your class is in a package and you need to reference it with its full package name.

Comment: @Macjay if it works, maybe you should accept his answer and upvote it.

Comment: Also, package names conventionally comprise only lower-case letters, as well as digits.

Comment: @Alex Jone  I did but it won't show until I get more rep

Comment: Good hints! Saves my time.